# HTML5 slide show effect

Tags: javascript, css, html

I saw some slides shows like 
http://slides.html5rocks.com and 
http://www.htmlfivewow.com

When you press left or right keys, you will see the slide cube effect.
I want to make simple webpage with these effects, just several div. I tried to get css and javascript out of the source code, but the slides cannot work the same.

1. when animating, the div don't have a 3D style, It just moves and rotates. In fact http://slides.html5rocks.com does not have the 3D effect in my firefox, while it has in Chrome.
2. Is there any tutorial?
3. How can this work in IE 10?

Here is some of my code:
html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="div1" class="main slide current"> ... </div>
    <div id="div2" class="main slide future"> ... </div>
    <div id="div3" class="main slide future"> ... </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.container {
    height: 100%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:800px;
    overflow: visible;
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.main{
    border: 1px solid;
    border-color: white;
    border-radius: 15px 15px 0 0 ;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 450px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
}

.slide {
    width: 800px;
    height: 450px;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.8s ease-in-out, opacity 1.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.8s ease-in-out, opacity 1.2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -moz-box-orient: vertical;
    box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
}
.slide.past {
    z-index: 8;
    visibility: visible;
    display: block;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(-400px) rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(400px);
    -moz-transform: translateZ(-400px) rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(400px);
    -o-transform: translateZ(-400px) rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(6400px);
    transform: translateZ(-400px) rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(400px);
}
.slide.current {
    z-index: 9;
    visibility: visible;
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(-400px) rotateY(0deg) translateZ(400px);
    -moz-transform: translateZ(-400px) rotateY(0deg) translateZ(400px);
    -o-transform: translateZ(-400px) rotateY(0deg) translateZ(400px);
    transform: translateZ(-400px) rotateY(0deg) translateZ(400px);
}
.slide.future {
    z-index: 8;
    visibility: visible;
    display: block;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(-400px) rotateY(90deg) translateZ(400px);
    -moz-transform: translateZ(-400px) rotateY(90deg) translateZ(400px);
    -o-transform: translateZ(-400px) rotateY(90deg) translateZ(400px);
    transform: translateZ(-400px) rotateY(90deg) translateZ(400px);
}
```

script:

```
$("#div1").attr("class", "main slide future");
$("#div2").attr("class", "main slide current");
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<h1>Slider</h1>
<div id="slider">
  <a href="#" class="control_next">>></a>
  <a href="#" class="control_prev"><</a>
  <ul>
    <li>SLIDE 1</li>
    <li style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 2</li>
    <li>SLIDE 3</li>
    <li style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 4</li>
  </ul>  
</div>

<div class="slider_option">
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox">
  <label for="checkbox">Autoplay Slider</label>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html {
  border-top: 5px solid #fff;
  background: #58DDAF;
  color: #2a2a2a;
}

html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
}

h1 {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 300;
}

#slider {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

#slider ul {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 200px;
  list-style: none;
}

#slider ul li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 300px;
}

a.control_prev, a.control_next {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  z-index: 999;
  display: block;
  padding: 4% 3%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  background: #2a2a2a;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 18px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  cursor: pointer;
}

a.control_prev:hover, a.control_next:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

a.control_prev {
  border-radius: 0 2px 2px 0;
}

a.control_next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
}

.slider_option {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 160px;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

javascript

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

  $('#checkbox').change(function(){
    setInterval(function () {
        moveRight();
    }, 3000);
  });

    var slideCount = $('#slider ul li').length;
    var slideWidth = $('#slider ul li').width();
    var slideHeight = $('#slider ul li').height();
    var sliderUlWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;

    $('#slider').css({ width: slideWidth, height: slideHeight });

    $('#slider ul').css({ width: sliderUlWidth, marginLeft: - slideWidth });

    $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');

    function moveLeft() {
        $('#slider ul').animate({
            left: + slideWidth
        }, 200, function () {
            $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');
            $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
        });
    };

    function moveRight() {
        $('#slider ul').animate({
            left: - slideWidth
        }, 200, function () {
            $('#slider ul li:first-child').appendTo('#slider ul');
            $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
        });
    };

    $('a.control_prev').click(function () {
        moveLeft();
    });

    $('a.control_next').click(function () {
        moveRight();
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But there is no 3D style. Especially, I mean, 3D rotating when moving left or right, at the same time changing size of the slide.